# WCF async call runs synchronously instead

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I'm practicing WCF Async calls, yet I can't get it to run async.

The code is very simple

```
protected void btnGetEvals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EvalServiceClient client = new EvalServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IEvalService");
    client.GetEvalsCompleted += client_GetEvalsCompleted;
    client.GetEvalsAsync();
    Label1.Text = "Waiting...";
    //client.Close();
}

void client_GetEvalsCompleted(object sender, GetEvalsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = e.Result;
    GridView1.DataBind();             
}
```

And here's the service

```
public class EvalService : IEvalService
{
    List<Eval> evals = new List<Eval>();

    public void SubmitEval(Eval eval)
    {
        evals.Add(eval);
    }

    public List<Eval> GetEvals()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return evals;
    }
}
```

When I click btnGetEvals, I should see "Waiting..." immediately while the service executes and returns evals. Instead, both take 5 seconds, and evals with "Waiting..." appear at the same time.

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20b2e236-b43c-431b-a51e-24c5250b64cf/wcf-async-call-not-working), which suggests closing the client in the completed callback, so for now I just commented it out (because I don't know how to close it in the completed callback. Any help in that department would also be appreciated). Well, that didn't help. And yes my service references are already set to allow ansync operations.

I'm a bit at a loss here. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.5/C# 5.0 you can use the await/async pattern - much easier to use.

Comment: Break the debugger while the call is running. What is on the stack on the UI thread? Show external code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an overview of the steps to achieve WFC async calls

- Declare two relevant method: one as **BeginMethodName** and another as
  **EndMethodName**.
- Add **[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]** to the relevant **Begin method**.
- Do not provide the **OperationContract** attribute to the corresponding **End method**.
- In the service implementation, the actual processing should go in a method, and this method should run on a separate thread, to achieve this you can use **ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.**
- On the client side, **call the relevant Begin method, but do not close the proxy after this because the End method needs the same channel to get the result**. You can close it in the client's callback after calling the End method.

**All the details to achieve WCF asyn calls are here here**

**http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121345/Asynchronous-Communication-in-a-WCF-Service**

Comment: That's on the server side. Also ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is not the way to make a WCF server async.

Comment: @usr I am just summarizing what I found. What it says is that the actual method needs to run on a separate thread and QueueUserWorkItem is just one of the ways to do it. Besides I mention client and server side

Comment: I'll work through this article and let you know what comes of it. Thanks for the resource!